# Executing T-SQL query from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MergeTable @TableName VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(max)
    SET @Test = (SELECT Query
                 FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH
                 WHERE SourceTableName = @TableName)

    EXEC @Test
END
GO

EXEC MergeTable @TableName = 'SGPREINVOICE'
```

The table `dbo.QueryMergeDWH` holds queries for different tables I want to run using the stored procedure. The variable @Test holds the query (a MERGE statement) for the table 'SGPREINVOICE' in this case.

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MergeTable, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 19]
> The name 'MERGE dwh.SGPREINVOICE t
> USING stg.SGPREINVOICE s
> ON t.VOUCHER = s.VOUCHER
> WHEN NOT MATCHED
> THEN INSERT VALUES (BATCHNAME, COMPANYNR, BUDGETHOUDER, VENDORNR, BANKACCOUNTID, [DESCRIPTION], EXTERNALINVOICENR, TAXVERLEGD, INVOICEDATE, BOOKINGDATE, INVOICEAMOUNTDEB, INVOICEAMOUNTCRED, SGAMOUNTHIGH, SGAMOUNTLOW, SGAMOUNTNOTAX, SGTAXAMOUNTLOW, SGTAXAMOUNTHIGH, SGTAXTTV, G_ACCOUNT, G_AMOUNT, INVOICETYPE, SGAUTOINCASSO, SGIMPORTPROCESSID, SGINVOICEBLOCKED, SGCOMPANYNRORIG, SGVENDORNRORIG, SGBANKACCOUNTIDORIG, SGG_ACCOUNTORIG, SGPOSTBUSNR, SGADDRESS, SGHUISNR, SGHUISNRTOEV, SGPOSTCODE, SGWOONPL, SGBTWNR, SGBEDRIJFSNM, SGINVOICEAMOUNTORIG, V' is not a valid identifier.

It seems like the variable `@Test` does not contain the entire statement but only part of it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What you're doing is little different from creating multiple stored procedures, except you have no idea if there are any errors until you actually execute the query. You can't apply permissions on those queries either, they way you can with stored procedures. No parameters either

Comment: I think this is related to your previous question about dynamic SQL  ?? @Luuk van Gasteren

Comment: `the variabel @Test does not contain the entire statement ` is the statement already truncated perhaps? What's the table schema are the contents of `Query`? The query may have been truncated when it was written. Besides, the query itself would cause problems if there are more than 1 rows for the same table. There's no way to tell *which* of them will be returned

Comment: The easy solution to this problem is to not use that table. Use stored procedures.

Comment: Read carefully all the comments. But I think, that the reason for this error is the difference between `EXEC @Test` (to execute a stored procedure or function) and `EXEC (@Test)` (to execute a dynamic statement).

Comment: The form [EXEC @storedProcName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-execute-with-a-stored-procedure-variable) executes the stored procedure whose name is stored in `@storedProcName`. `EXEC` is a bit of a fossil though as it can't be used with parameterized queries. That's why [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason for this error is the difference between `EXEC @Test` (to execute a stored procedure or function) and `EXEC (@Test)` (to execute a dynamic statement). Note, that you may use `sp_executesql` to execute a dynamically generated statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MergeTable @TableName VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(max)
    
    SELECT @Test = Query
    FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH
    WHERE SourceTableName = @TableName

    EXEC (@Test)
    -- Or using sp_executesql
    -- DECLARE @err int
    -- EXEC @err = sp_executesql @Test
    -- IF @err <> 0 PRINT 'Error'
END
GO

EXEC MergeTable @TableName = 'SGPREINVOICE'
```